# Expected value of the sum of digits from 0 to 9999.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

We choose a number from the set $\{0,...,9999\}$ randomly, and
denote by $X$ the sum of its digits. Find the expected value of $X$.

If we are letting $X$ be in the sum of digits, you can specify $X=a+b+c+d$ for $0\le a,b,c,d,<10$ with $0 \le X \le 36.$ I think I am supposed to use indicators, but can't seem to define what a success would be among picking digits, and the relation to the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: By Linearity of Expectation, $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[a+b+c+d] = \mathbb{E}[a]+\mathbb{E}[b]+\mathbb{E}[c]+\mathbb{E}[d]$.

Can you work out the expected value of each digit?

Comment: Should it just be 18 then

Comment: ^Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, was trying to make it much more complex than needed.